# How can I replace DOM node within memory using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, memory, replace

I have the following code

```
$.getJSON("../services/getNavigationAffectedList.php", obj, function(response)
{
    $.each(response, function(i, v)
    {
        // Get the old page source
        var source = v;

        // Get the updated preview HTML
        var new_nav = $('#preview').find('#navigation-block').html();

        // Replace the old navigation with the preview HTML
        $(source).find('.navigation-block').html(new_nav);
        var source = $(source).html();

        var obj = {
            page_path: i,
            new_source: source
        };
        console.log(obj);
    });
```

Which is attempting to replace the navigation-block class within the DOM contained in memory (source). Although, $(source).html() does not yield expected results.

Help?

Partial JSON response per David's request:

> {"\/var\/www\/html\/cms\/sites\/about\/debbie.php":"\r\n
>   ... tons more html here ....}

Here is a fiddle to test with:
http://jsfiddle.net/eZP9E/1/

Comment: Could you include a small example of the JSON, or (even better) a link that demonstrates the problem? http://jsfiddle.net is a great tool if you don't have a live link.

Comment: {"\/var\/www\/html\/cms\/sites\/about\/debbie.php":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-\/\/W3C\/\/DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict\/\/EN\" \"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/TR\/xhtml1\/DTD\/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n ... tons more html here ....}

Comment: @syn4k: I'm sorry, what was the last comment supposed to be? Edit additional details **into the question**, not the **comments**.

Comment: @David, the last comment was in response to Matt's request for an example of the JSON

Comment: @syn4k, ah, okay. Um, could you edit it into the question? It's additional information that can inform the answers, and so forms a *part of* the question itself, rather than discussion, or thoughts, *about* the question which is the purpose/use of the comments system. =)

Comment: Here is a fiddle for you to test with: http://jsfiddle.net/eZP9E/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery's replaceWith function. Is this what you're looking for?

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

What is the un-desired result you are getting?

**UPDATE:** Turns out the problem is with the way it's creating the DOM elements in jQuery.

Your code expects the 'var original' is the  element, but it isnt.

```
var container = $('<html><body><div class="navigation">1</div></body></html>');
alert(container.length); // returns 1, div.navigation

var container = $('<html><body><div class="navigation">1</div><div class="body"></div></body></html>');
alert(container.length); // returns 2, div.navigation, div.body

var container = $('<div id="root"><html><body><div class="navigation">1</div></body></html></div>');
alert(container.length); // returns 1, sweet! we can use this
```

After some testing, these are the results that I have from the code above.

The quick solution for your issue would be to update the code to something like this:

```
var original = $('<div id="root">' + v + '</div>', document);
```

Comment: interestingly, replaceWith only seems to work with page DOMs instead of memory DOMs as in my snippet.

Comment: @syn4k, I've updated my answer. I've made the single update to your fiddle and it worked like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/eZP9E/3/